# preg_replace only part of match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using `preg_replace` to create urls for modrewrite based paging links.
I use:

`$nextURL = preg_replace('%/([\d]+)/%','/'.($pageNumber+1).'/',$currentURL);`

which works fine, however I was wondering if there is a better way without having to include the `'/'` in the replacement parameter. I need to match the number as being between two `/` as the URLs can sometimes contain numbers other than the page part. These numbers are never only numbers however, so have `/[\d]+/` stops them from getting replaced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
 %(?<=/)([\d]+)(?=/)%
```

`(?<=…)` is a positive look-behind assertion and `(?=…)` a positive look-ahead assertion. The regular expression `(?<=/)([\d]+)(?=/)` is to be interpreted as follows:

- `(?<=/)` – if there is a `/` in behind the current position
- `([\d]+)` – match one or more digits
- `(?=/)` – but only if there is a `/` after that

You can also simplify your expression as follows:

```
preg_replace('%(?<=/)\d+(?=/)%', $pageNumber+1, $currentURL)
```

Comment: +1 The expression can be simplified further to just `%(?<=/)\d+(?=/)%`, no need to put all the brackets around `\d`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was something like that, but I couldn't remember what they were called or how they worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$nextURL = preg_replace('%(?<=/)([\d]+)(?=/)%',($pageNumber+1),$currentURL);
```